# Proof of the Friedlander–Iwaniec theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Does anybody know where I could find the proof of the Friedlander–Iwaniec theorem. The link that I find when I search for it is http://www.pnas.org/content/94/4/1054.full.pdf+html, but this seems more like an outline of the proof than the proof itself. Also, I have been told that the proof is much longer than 4-5 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J. Friedlander and H. Iwaniec, The polynomial $X^2+Y^4$ captures its primes. Ann. of Math. (2) 148 (1998), no. 3, 945--1040.

see:

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1670069

http://www.jstor.org/stable/121034?origin=crossref

Comment: The article appeared also in the arxiv - http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811185.pdf